# matplotlibe ticker trouble: MaxNLocator doesnt seem to have the right attributes

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I try to run the example script at 
http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/pcolormesh_levels.html 
in ipython, I get

```
In [1]: %run cmap.py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
    173             else:
    174                 filename = fname
--> 175             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

/home/qlnr92/Dropbox/bin/cmap.py in <module>()
     11 cmap = plt.get_cmap('PiYG')
     12 
---> 13 levels = MaxNLocator(nbins=15).tick_values(z.min(), z.max())
     14 norm = BoundaryNorm(levels, ncolors=cmap.N, clip=True)
     15 

AttributeError: MaxNLocator instance has no attribute 'tick_values'
```

also

```
In [18]: dir(levels)
Out[18]: 
['DummyAxis',
'MAXTICKS',
'__call__',
'__doc__',
'__init__',
'__module__',
'_integer',
'_nbins',
'_prune',
'_steps',
'_symmetric',
'_trim',
'autoscale',
'axis',
'bin_boundaries',
'create_dummy_axis',
'default_params',
'pan',
'raise_if_exceeds',
'refresh',
'set_axis',
'set_bounds',
'set_data_interval',
'set_params',
'set_view_interval',
'view_limits',
'zoom']
```

I'm pretty new to matplotlib so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I'm pretty sure all the packages are okay because if I comment out anything containing the `levels` variable (which is the object to which the output of the `tick_values` method is assigned) then the plots come out nicely. However, I'd like to know what's going wrong.

(to be on the safe side, here's the slightly edited script i've used in ipython --pylab

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
import numpy as np


dx, dy = 0.05, 0.05

y, x = np.mgrid[slice(1, 5 + dy, dy),
                slice(1, 5 + dx, dx)]

z = np.sin(x) ** 10 + np.cos(10 + y * x) * np.cos(x)

z = z[:-1, :-1]
levels = MaxNLocator(nbins=15).tick_values(z.min(), z.max())

cmap = plt.get_cmap('PiYG')
norm = BoundaryNorm(levels, ncolors=cmap.N, clip=True)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
im = plt.pcolormesh(x, y, z, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
plt.colorbar()
plt.axis([x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])
plt.title('pcolormesh with levels')

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.contourf(x[:-1, :-1] + dx / 2.,
             y[:-1, :-1] + dy / 2., z, levels=levels,
             cmap=cmap)
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('contourf with levels')

plt.show()
```

)

Comment: What version of mpl are you using?  I can not reproduce this, the example runs correctly on my system.

Comment: Not at the right machine atm, but it was the most recent version available via synaptic (ubuntu 12.04), which I believe is 1.1.1. 

I see now they're up to 1.3, so maybe I should've checked the version number!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the method I was using has been replaced by the `bin_boundaries` method. `tick_values` doesn't seem to exist anymore...

see Locator?? MaxNLocator?? and other inherited class documentation